# Oracle - Arranging rows based on date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Source data:

```
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| ID | AUTH_ROLE_NM    | ROLE | ST_DT         | END_DT        |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | channel_manager | A    | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2017 00 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | channel_manager | C    | 01.01.2017 01 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | channel_manager | D    | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | market manager  | B    | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | market manager  | E    | 01.01.2017 02 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+
```

Target data

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| ID | chnl_mngr | mrkt mngr | ST_DT         | END_DT        |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | A         | B         | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2017 00 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | C         | B         | 01.01.2017 01 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | D         |           | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | D         | E         | 01.01.2017 02 | 01.01.2999 00 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Explanation, In the output set,

- Row1 - For ID 1 A was channel mgr and B was mktmgr for the daterange
- Row2 - For ID 1 C was channel mgr and B was mktmgr for the daterange
- Row3 - For ID 2 D was channel mgr and there was no mktmgr for the daterange
- Row4 - For ID 2 A was channel mgr and E was mktmgr for the daterange

How can I achieve the target set?

```
select id,
st_dt,
END_dt,
max(case when auth_role_name = 'channel_manager' then hotel_role_name end) as channel_manager,
max(case when auth_role_name = 'market manager' then hotel_role_name end) as market_manager 
from source
group by 
id,
st_dt,
END_dt
```

I have tried something like this, but I am stuck with the date range scenario.

Comment: the explanation for third row in the output isn't clear.

Comment: when 3rd was created, at the initial hour there was no mkt_mgr for ID 2. mkt_mgr row for id 2 was created after 1 hour. So for a duration of 1 hour we have kept the mkt_mgr as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

Please check below query can help.

```
    with data as
(select 1 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'A'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2017 00'as END_DT  from dual  
 union
 select 1 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'C'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 01'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT  from dual    
 union
 select 2 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'D'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT  from dual   
 union
 select 1 as ID ,'market manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM     ,'B'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT   from dual    
 union
 select 2 as ID ,'market manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM     ,'E'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 02'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT    from dual  
 )
select a.id , a.role as chnl_mngr , 
case when  (to_date(b.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') <=to_date(a.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') and a.id = b.id)
or (b.ST_DT<=a.END_DT and a.id = b.id)
then
b.role else null end as mrkt_mngr ,
case when a.id = b.id and b.ST_DT>=a.ST_DT then b.ST_DT else  a.ST_DT end ST_DT ,
--b.ST_DT ,
b.END_DT  
from  data  a 
left outer join (select id , role ,  ST_DT , END_DT 
from  data where AUTH_ROLE_NM = 'market manager' ) b
on a.id = b.id
or to_date(a.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') >= to_date(b.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') 
where AUTH_ROLE_NM = 'channel_manager'
order by 1
;
```

**Updated Query:** Updating query according to "How can I make the third output row as `2|D| | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2017 02`"

```
 with data as
(select 1 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'A'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2017 00'as END_DT  from dual  
 union
 select 1 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'C'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 01'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT  from dual    
 union
 select 2 as ID ,'channel_manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM    ,'D'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT  from dual   
 union
 select 1 as ID ,'market manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM     ,'B'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 00'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT   from dual    
 union
 select 2 as ID ,'market manager'as AUTH_ROLE_NM     ,'E'as ROLE ,'01.01.2017 02'as ST_DT  ,'01.01.2999 00'as END_DT    from dual  
 )
select a.id , a.role as chnl_mngr , 
case when  (to_date(b.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') <=to_date(a.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') and a.id = b.id)
or (b.ST_DT<=a.END_DT and a.id = b.id)
then
b.role else null end as mrkt_mngr ,
case when a.id = b.id and b.ST_DT>=a.ST_DT then b.ST_DT else  a.ST_DT end ST_DT ,
--b.ST_DT ,
case when 
  lead(b.ST_DT) over(partition by a.id order by a.ST_DT )>= to_date(a.ST_DT)
then lead(b.ST_DT) over(partition by a.id order by a.ST_DT ) else  b.END_DT   end END_DT
from  data  a 
left outer join (select id , role ,  ST_DT , END_DT 
from  data where AUTH_ROLE_NM = 'market manager' ) b
on a.id = b.id
or to_date(a.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') >= to_date(b.ST_DT,'dd:mm:rrrr hh24') 
where AUTH_ROLE_NM = 'channel_manager'
order by 1
;
```

Comment: How can I make the third output row as `2|D| | 01.01.2017 00 | 01.01.2017 02`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Please check updated query. hoping it will solve your problem.